# Chrome remote debugging - a blank page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The remote debugging in chrome suddenly stopped working me. I'm getting a black popup page after clicking on the 'inspect' link under the app. Also, not sure if this is related but the console view in dev tools on the chrome://inspect/ page is throwing the error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_assets/www/assets...` This occurs on different apps.

My chrome version is 56.0.2924.87 (On Ubuntu 16.10)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to update Chrome on your PC. I had the same issue, and my Chrome was telling me it was on the latest version, but:

Head to `Chrome > Help > About Google Chrome` and this should automatically trigger an update to `Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Hope this helps, it was bugging me for days.

Comment: Does not trigger an update for me (Ubuntu 17.10). Chrome version is still 64.0.3282.140

Comment: There's a Linux version of this build here: https://www.techspot.com/downloads/4718-google-chrome-for-windows.html, although I haven't been able to test this from my PC (Windows 10) - this may sort it for you.

Comment: Sorry, that link does have a Linux option but there's also a direct link here: https://www.techspot.com/downloads/4909-google-chrome-for-linux.html

Comment: `apt upgrade` did the trick! Now have version 65.0.3325.146 and remote debugging is working once again \o/